# distance and direction using OSM

Tags: python, openstreetmap, directions

I'm trying to find a package that will give me the distance and turn by turn directions between two points in a list format, preferably using offline OSM files.  I have tried different packages including OSMnx and OSMium but they all give graphical information. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org) has a page about [Routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) and a page about [Android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) where several software and libraries are listed. One of them is [GraphHopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper), also take a look at the [GraphHopper Android example](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md).

Comment: I am trying to obtain distance, directions and landmarks (such as bus stops and parks) in such a format that I can use them for recreating the route in a game. I am interested in reading these values into python. I have tried OSRM but it only outputs the route in a graphical way, doesn't give me the values for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by graphical information, but you can do this with OSMnx. To get the network distance between two points you can use the example in the [routing section](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/00-osmnx-features-demo.ipynb) of this demo. To get the turns, you can take the list of edges in the route and look at their compass-bearings pairwise. See the OSMnx documentation for how to work with edge bearings: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/